# Which namespace should I use for my Asp.NET MVC 4 beta Filters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement a global exception handler in Asp.NET MVC 4 beta. As I understand it I am supposed to implement an `IExceptionFilter` and add that to the filters collection. However I was unable to make it work when using the `System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter`. Am I supposed to use that one, or is the `System.Web.Http.Filters.IExceptionFilter` (and related classes) the ones I should be using?

Asking another way:

Should I be adding filters to the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters` or `GlobalFilters.Filters`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Web.Http` namespace completely belongs to ASP.NET Web API framework, not ASP.NET MVC.

As for the registration point, you need to add them into `GlobalFilters.Filters` collection.

Comment: That's what confuses me actually. As I understand it, ASP.NET Web API is now part of ASP.NET MVC 4. So when I want to make a rest service using ASP.NET Web API, I make controllers and routes like I would for an MVC app. But I'm still not sure what namespace I should use.

Comment: `GlobalFilters.Filters` is part of mvc, so I assume that I should then add `System.Web.Mvc.IExceptionFilter`s to it if that's the collection I should be using?

Comment: @Mithon It is a common misunderstanding going on right now. Actually, Web API framework is not part of ASP.NET MVC. It has a very similar programming and processing model as MVC framework. It also ships with MVC (at least for now). When you have a close look, you will see that it has no dependency on MVC assemblies. As I mentioned above, `System.Web.Http` namespace completely belongs to ASP.NET Web API framework, not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: So I should in fact be using the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters` in my case? I am deriving my controllers from ApiController which, as you say is in the `System.Web.Http` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

So after getting some pointers from @tugberk, I realize my mistake. I was basically asking for the wrong thing. What I wanted was to be able to add filters for an ASP.NET Web API service, not add them for an mvc application.

I made this error thinking they were one and the same. I guess I must have read som of what was said about moving these things together the wrong way.

In any case. I should be using the `System.Web.Http` namespace for my case, which means adding to the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters` collection.

I found a rather nice [weblog](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2012/02/27/handling-exceptions-in-your-asp-net-web-api.aspx) showing a basic implementation of some of what I want to accomplish. Maybe it can help somebody else.